# GitLab CI - forced start of job during manual start of another job

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a dependency problem. My pipeline looks like it gets the dependencies required for jobs first, and finally runs a stage cleanup that cleans them all. The problem is that I have one stage with manual launch which also needs these dependencies but they are cleared.

Question can I somehow run a stage which has dependencies by running a manual stage? is there any other way i can solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the dependencies are cleaned up? If the dependencies are files, you can save them as artifacts.

Comment: You should post an example of your pipeline to get a better answer

Comment: @DavideMadrisan 
dependencies I mean the stage which clones the repository and finally the cleanup cleans the files and then another job cannot find the necessary directories.

Answer (score 0):

The normal behaviour of GitLab-CI is to clone the git repository at each job because the jobs can be run on different runners and thus need to be independent.

The automatic clone can be disabled by adding:

```
job-with-no-git-clone:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

If you need to use in a job some files/directories created in a previous stage, you must add them as GitLab [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html)

```
stages:
  - one
  - two

job-with-git-clone:
  stage: one
  script:
      # this script creates something in the folder data
      # (which means $CI_PROJECT_DIR/data)
      do_something()
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - data/

job2-with-git-clone:
  stage: two
  script:
    # here you can use the files created in data

job2-with-no-git-clone:
  stage: two
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    # here you can use the files created in data
```

Comment: okej thank very much i understood but i have problem with my paths artifact. In next job get message: bash: line 115: cd: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Sty-uGsY/0/wwwDev/project-app/../project-root: No such file or directory. so what should my path be in path artifact?

Comment: I cannot understand the `/project-app/../project-root` part in your path. The only important limitation of an artifact is that you cannot write outside $CI_PROJECT_DIR. This maybe is the root cause of your issue. Please share your code. Will be easier to understand the problem.